# Java: Intersection detection of one line segment against many lines segments

Tags: java, intersection

I have a collection of lines segments. Now I want to add another line segment and I want to ensure that he is not intersect with any of my lines.

Do I need to run over all my lines or there is any better algorithm for that?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest and possibly computationally cheap just to iterate over all the lines.

The lines I assume are all independent of each other so have no relation to any other line so it not intersecting with one doesn't mean it won't intersect with another.

The only other cheap way I can think of is to create a boundary around all the current lines (easy one is a square), if your new line doesn't enter the square then you know it won't intersect any of the other lines.

Comment: Its not perfect but this is a nice idea